# Mails from local server not being delivered properly

Tags: email, office365, phabricator

I have a local phabricator server which triggers mail for every commit and email is generated through postfix and emails are delivered to Office 365 accounts. I observe that some mails are not being delivered. Only 60% of them are being delivered approximately. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: can you post a log message about a mail that was not delivered?

Comment: there is no error as such i could see mail is sent to quque. all i want is to get these mails triggered by local server to be delivered to respective collagues office365 accounts . it would be helpful if u can suggest a way.  i could see microsoft direct send as a way but couldnt see anay way to implement it.